# Selecting option in select from javascript does stops working in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, selected

I am setting the selected option in a select group but this only works the first couple of times. This only seems to be an issue in Chrome. How can I make this work in Chrome?

In the example below press the 1 and 2 buttons a few times and you can see that it stops working in chrome but continues to work in IE.

https://jsfiddle.net/beerkensp/3ej6980x/

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="1" />
<input type="button" id="button2" value="2" />

<select class="form-control" id="mySelect" size="4">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

var onClick = function() {
        var $buttonVal=$(this).val ();
    $('#mySelect option').each (function () {
        //alert ($(this).val ());
        if ($(this).val ()==$buttonVal)
      {
        $(this).attr ("selected",true);
      } else
      {
      $(this).attr ("selected",false);
      }
    })
};

$('#button').click(onClick);
$('#button2').click(onClick);
```

Comment: change `attr` to `prop`

Comment: I'm not getting that problem... What version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: I am using this version of chrome: 51.0.2704.106 m

Comment: Changing attr to prop fixed the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `attr()`

Here is an updated [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3ej6980x/1/)

```js
var onClick = function() {
  var $buttonVal = $(this).val();
  $('#mySelect option').each(function() {
    //alert ($(this).val ());
    if ($(this).val() == $buttonVal) {
      $(this).prop("selected", true);
    } else {
      $(this).prop("selected", false);
    }
  })
};

$('#button').click(onClick);
$('#button2').click(onClick);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="button" value="1" />
<input type="button" id="button2" value="2" />

<select class="form-control" id="mySelect" size="4">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```